# How do I create a table in MS-Access using VBA NOT in currentdb

Tags: vba, ms-access

First time user here.  I need to create a new table in Access using VBA but NOT in the currentdb. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,
Rimuru

Comment: Establish connection to other db and run CREATE TABLE sql. https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-automation-external-access-database-create-table/. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you can do this.

Firstly, you can use SQL to do this:

```vb
Sub sCreateTable1()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("J:\downloads\test.accdb")
    db.Execute "CREATE TABLE [test1] (Field1 CHAR);"
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Secondly, you can use DAO to do this:

```vb
Sub sCreateTable2()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("J:\downloads\test.accdb")
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("test2")
    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("Field1", dbText, 100)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld
    db.TableDefs.Append tdf
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much!